# Lambda check if list contains certain property values on all properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

Pretty hard to explain in the topic, but how do i know if ALL of the lists `x.someprop` matches the value `7`? In other words, if the filter below returns the entire list:

```
myList.Where( x => x.someprop == 7).ToList();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)

```
bool result = myList.All( x => x.someprop == 7);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can invert the condition and use [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)

```
bool areAllSeven = myList.Any(x => x.someprop != 7);
```

Answer (score 1):

How hard have you tried to find the answer?

```
bool areAllEqualToSeven = myList.All( x => x.someprop == 7);
```

Comment: Yes, didnt really know how to search for this

Comment: I usually use IntelliSense and provided documentation to find quick solutions.

Comment: Yea but i was refering to my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The name of the method is easy to remember: [**`All`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx):

```
bool allSeven = myList.All(x => x.someprop == 7);
```

> This method does not return all the elements of a collection. Instead, it determines whether all the elements of a collection satisfy a condition.